# How to create a real time link between Raspberry pi3 and Android app to see sensor info?

Tags: pi-3, android

I built an App (android) and a little Car (Raspberry Pi 3 b+). The app is a remote control and I put a proximity sensor to the Raspberry (little car).

How can i do to get that info in real time in the android app ? what kind of technology should i use? Thanks!

PD: I'm using Kotlin in the remote control

Comment: Hi @German Jr. Let me see.  There are many kinds of technology for remote control, including (1) WiFi and (2) BlueTooth.  For Wifi, you can start with the Wifi controller, ESP8266.  You might watch this video to get a rough idea of how a smart phone can talk to ESP8266 to control a garage door: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpwEa_48-Cw.  Or this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYtqeb6YjwA.  Of course you can google more.

Comment: Yes, the smart phone above can talk to Rpi which in turn control GPIO pins to switch on/off the garage door motor or similar things.  Now let me make things more complicated, adding Bluetooth stuff.  This time you can get a "Bluetooth serial module". Rpi talks to this directly wire connected module using serial (two physical wires for UART TxD, RxD, 9,600 N81).  The smart phone Wifi connects/pairs with the BT module, using an app, something like "BlueSerialApp" etc.  Then Rpi can talk to smart phone "indirectly" in serial UART, send texts like "turn left, then go straight 5 seconds etc ..."